# WebSockets how to identify binary data continuation frame?

Tags: java, javascript, html, websocket

```
                            byte[] b = new byte[buffLent]; // buffLent = 10000
                            len = readerIn.read(b); //InputStream
                            System.out.println("FIRST BYTE: " + b[0]);
                            System.out.println("SECOND BYTE: " + b[1]);
                            System.out.println("THIRD BYTE: " + b[2]);
                            if(b[0] == 0x82)
                            {

                                //its binary

                            }
```

in this code I can detect the begining of binary data, if the file is small then I can read it fully, but if its too big, then it splits into parts, which hex code I should use to detect the continuation of binary data? cause as I tested it, the first byte becomes a length of current frame, so here I'am stucked, any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2

> - %x0 denotes a continuation frame